# Foundation Zurb unable to change tooltip text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I’m having a problem changing the tooltip text on runtime after the tooltip text has already been set. Please see below for more information.

Please can I have the correct code to change the tooltip text or a work around for the below problem?

As an example I've created a blank html page, with one label, and 2 buttons:

```
<body>

<div class="row" style='padding-top:20px;'>
<div class="large-12 columns">
<label id='labelID'> my Tooltip label</label>

<input type='button' class='button' id='addFirstTooltip' value='Add First Tooltip'/>
<input type='button' class='button' id='changeTooltip' disabled value='Change Tooltip'/>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $(document).on('click', '[id^=addFirstTooltip]', function()
  {
     $('#labelID').attr('data-tooltip', '');
     $('#labelID').attr('title', 'My First tooltip text. This displays correctly.');

     $('#changeTooltip').removeAttr('disabled');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '[id^=changeTooltip]', function()
  {
     $('#labelID').attr('title', 'Now ive changed the tooltip text. Not displaying correctly.');
  });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Okay so clicking the first button "addFirstTooltip" correctly adds the foundation tooltip. No problem at all. But as soon as you change the tooltip text ("changeTooltip" button), it basically creates an addition stock html tooltip with the new text, and does not change the original foundation tooltip text.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

After much trial and error and looking through the code... I figured this out!

```
Foundation.libs.tooltips.getTip($('#labelID')).remove();
```

Call that code after removing the attribute title, and call afftr('title', 'new tooltip text') after that! And boom! it works!

Comment: That worked for me but I changed tooltips to tooltip, look like this Foundation.libs.tooltip.getTip($('#labelID')).remove();. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime this is:

```
Foundation.libs.tooltip.getTip($('#labelID')).remove();
```

After that you have to call:

```
$('#labelID').attr('title','Your new title');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to answer this question more simply...
Foundation generates a new span for the content of each tooltip on page load (class="tooltip"). You are welcome to change the element title, but it won't change the tooltip after load. Instead, change the span element content.

```
thingy = $('#labelID'); // element whose tooltip you want to change
wich = $("has-tip").index(thingy); // which has-tip element is it? [int]
say = "here's the new tooltip content"; // new tooltip content
$(".tooltip").eq(wich).html(say); // assign span content
```

You won't need to reflow after this or anything. It will just work.

Comment: This is a simple solution that doesn't require you to remove any content. Thanks @scot-nery!

Comment: As at foundation 6.1.1 this doesn't work but the following does: `var tooltipId = $("#my-element.has-tip").attr("data-toggle");  $("#"+tooltipId).html("new content");`

Comment: Hi @Scot Nery, this works but the position of the tooltip changes to top, any ideas how to retaing its original position?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tooltip by changing the html of the mapped tooltip element.

```
<p>
<a href="#" id="fav-123" class="item-display-button fav-button active" data-tooltip="" title="">test</a>
 </p>
<span data-selector="fav-123" class="tooltip" style="visibility: visible; display: none; width: auto; top: 31px; bottom: auto; left: auto; right: auto;">Changed!</span>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshaydulani/CA669/1392/)

Answer (score 0):

Lakshay is right, changing the html of the tooltip is the easiest and most efficient solution.
Here is the jQuery one-liner to achieve that:

```
Foundation.libs.tooltip.getTip($('#labelID')).contents().first().replaceWith('Changed');
```

where `labelID` is the ID of the element that has the tooltip, not the tooltip element itself.

Comment: Be careful if your new text is an empty string `''`. For example, if you replace  the tooltip with `''` and then try to replace it back to `'Changed'`, it won't work.